# display: css-table vs flex - do i even need the latter?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-tables, fallback

I've used to vertically center block-elements like this:

```
.parent {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -ms-grid-row-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

When I need IE9 and lower support. Using css-tables as a fall-back for older IE-s of course. I don't need flex for anything else. But recently I started to ask myself: why do I even need flex here? Css-table is a robust solution supported by virtually every browser in this planet and according to [this Ben Frain's article](https://benfrain.com/css-performance-test-flexbox-v-css-table-fight/) it's even faster. Isn't css-table enough here? When asking people about this I got answers like "flex is more modern" etc. That's fine and I do understand, that there are things that are only possible with flex, but it isn't really an answer here. We're talking about simplest centering block-elements.

So i have two questions:

1. Do i have to use flex in the case like this?
2. If "yes" - why?

Comment: Generally there is no single solution to a problem , so try to stick with one method which you are comfortable with and don't complicate it with things you don't understand completely as most often than not , it will be you who will have to review the code and make changes in future..

Comment: Check out [this post](http://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox) which shows some use cases where css tables can  be used instead of flexbox

Answer (score -1):

There's a reason we moved from using tables in HTML as a layouting tool.

It's not semantic. When we think of a table we think of a representation of data.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) explains it well.

> Prior to the creation of CSS, HTML  elements were often used as
>   a method for page layout. This usage has been discouraged since HTML
>   4, and the  element should not be used for layout purposes.
>   However, HTML emails are an exception where tables are still commonly
>   used for layout purposes. The reason for this is poor CSS support in
>   popular email clients.

So unless you're designing e-mail layouts do not use table elements or css table properties for layouting.

You can still use it if you need fallback hacks like in your example, but other than that use modern appropriate methods , be it grids ,flex , floats or whatever.

Comment: But i'm not speaking about **HTML-tabels** here - it's a completely different thing. **CSS-tables** are just forcing non-table elements to behave like table-elements. Isn't that what CSS is meant for? CSS is a styling language after all.

Comment: "CSS-tables are just forcing non-table elements to behave like table-elements." Well that's the problem. Are they tables? No? Then don't give them table properties.One on the problematic scenarios:  If I worked with you and saw in your CSS that you have some rules like .container { display: table } I'd think that that container IS a table. But if there was something like .container { display: flex} I'd knew that that container is helping you layout things.

Comment: What a ridiculous assertion: "don't give them table properties." How one styles something to achieve a specific design is almost totally irrelevant if it still uses semantic markup and behaves well, visually. When is `display: table` *not* for layout? Pedantic nonsense.